Azure AD B2C - Assigning a 'membership type' to users
sorry for another Azure AD B2C post, I am looking for some general advice on how to approach user 'memberships'. The service that is being provided has 3 membership levels - Bronze (basic access), Silver (advance access) and Gold (full access).
The basic idea is a user pays for their membership, then our admins onboard them into the Azure AD B2C through an external application, which grants them access and lets them log in/use the service.
Currently the Azure AD B2C is set up and the external app allows admins to onboard customers by inputting details to create their account. The next task is to assign a membership type to customers, I figured this could be done by adding 3 custom attributes (bronze, silver, gold) to the user properties, and then assigning a different user flow to each. The issue is I cannot figure out how to get the newly added 'user attributes' to show in a users properties.
New attributes
These do not appear in the user properties, even when creating a new user. If anyone can point me in the right direction or provide some documentation that could help I'd really appreciate it.
Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance!
I have read through Microsoft Custom policy overview and tutorial, it seems like a viable but overly complicated option as it involved downloading and editing a starter policy pack, and there is nothing in there about custom membership types.

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to assign those custom attributes to users?

Custom attributes are defined as extension properties to the user. The Portal UI does not allow you to enter them. You'll need to call MS Graph API to create users with extension properties. Personally I would not store these in Azure AD B2C, I'd rather have them in a database somewhere.

@Sridevi Yeah if possible.

@Juunas Ah I see, thankyou for the quick reply.
The plan is that the different properties (membership types) provide different levels of access to the service.
If I was to store these in a separate database, do you know how I'd direct users to their allocated service. (example if someone has signed up for bronze membership, then they have access to our bronze service).

Your best bet is to use User Groups.
You'll need to use Graph API to create user groups. However, you can assign users to various groups in the Azure portal (or Graph API).
User groups will allow you to easily take advantage of various security features in your app.
Here are some possible groups:

Admin
GoldMember
SilverMember
BronzeMember


This sounds perfect, I am unfamiliar with user groups so will look into it over the weekend and give it a go on Monday! Really appreciate the help, thankyou.

Just to note B2C does not natively support groups. You need to use Graph API as mentioned - https://damienbod.com/2021/09/06/using-azure-security-groups-in-asp-net-core-with-an-azure-b2c-identity-provider/
